# Read from file, clear it, write to it

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I'm trying to read data from a text file, clear it, and then write to it, in that order using the `fstream` class.

My question is how to clear a file after reading from it. I know that I can open a file and clear it at the same time, but is there some function I can call on the stream to clear its contents?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should open it, perform your input operations, and then close it and reopen it with the std::fstream::trunc flag set.

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("file", std::fstream::in);

    // read data

    f.close();
    f.open("file", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);

    // write data

    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be totally safe in the event of a crash or other disastrous event, you should do the write to a second, temporary file. Once finished, delete the first file and rename the temporary file to the first file. See the [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.htm) library for help in doing this.

Comment: Done like this, there's still a gap between the delete and the rename.  On UNIX filesystems, you should fsync, skip the delete, and just rename the temporary file over the first file; it will be atomically replaced.  On Windows, NTFS has a special ReplaceFile function; atomic replacements are not doable on other filesystems AFAIK.